# auto_increment usage in composite key

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am having a table with the composite key

```
emp_tbl(
companyId int not null,
empId int not null auto_increment,
name varchar2,
....
...
primary key(companyId,empId)
);
```

In mysql whats happening is while i starts inserting the data

Emp_tbl

```
companyId    empId
1             1
1             2
1             3
2             1
2             2
```

Note that when the companyId changes the auto_increament value is resetted to 1 again. I want to disable that. I mean i don't want to reset the auto_increament. I am expecting the result like this.

```
companyId    empId
1             1
1             2
1             3
2             4
2             5
```

Is it possible to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what happens with a composite primary key that incorporates a auto_increment. Recreate the primary key so that it's purely your auto_increment field (empId) then create a unique index on companyId and empId

**EDIT**

Note that this only applies to MyISAM and BDB tables. If you used InnoDB for your tables, then it would also work as you wanted

Comment: is there any way to make innodb work like MyISAM and BDB for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want empId to reset then just reverse the order of primary definition

```
primary key(companyId,empId)
```

note that composite key order matters.