# Mysql Auto-Increment Composite

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, auto-increment

I am trying to get the following to occur with my InnoDB using auto-increment

```
ID | AI
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    1
2    2
2    3
```

How do I set this up? I tried setting both as the PK but that didn't work like it seems to in other DB engines.

Google was of no help or perhaps I couldn't get the right search terms.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: What I found was people using different DB engines and someone trying to do the opposite of what I wanted to do. Didn't help too much: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804845/auto-increment-usage-in-composite-key

Comment: I saw this same type of question on here 4 days ago.

Comment: 4 days, that helped with searching. Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416548/mysql-two-column-primary-key-with-auto-increment#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to use a trigger.

Your table DDL might look like this

```
CREATE TABLE `composite` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ai` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`ai`)
);
```

And a trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER tg_comp_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON composite
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.ai = (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(ai), 0) + 1 FROM composite WHERE id = NEW.id);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then use it like this

```
INSERT INTO composite (id, ai) VALUES(1,0);
INSERT INTO composite (id, ai) VALUES(1,0);
```

The result will be

```
+----+----+
| id | ai |
+----+----+
|  1 |  1 |
|  1 |  2 |
+----+----+
```